# Terminate a thread in VC++

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++

I have created a VC++ thread using CreateThread() function,I want to know how to **terminate** the created thread from an outside function.

e.g.

```
 HANDLE Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread( NULL, 0,Thread_no_1, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, NULL);
```

```
void Thread_no_1
{
}
```

My question is how to terminate the Thread I have created from an outside function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `TerminateThread` function that you *can* use, but it should normally be reserved for dire emergencies. When you use it, the thread gets *no* chance to clean up after itself, which can easily leave the entire process in an unstable state.

Most of the time, you want to send some sort of signal to the thread to tell it to exit normally, releasing resources, etc., in the process. This can be done in several ways, such as setting an event it checks periodically.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `TerminateThread`, documented in MSDN. However, do be aware that this is generally a bad way to manage threads. From MSDN:

> TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases. You should call TerminateThread only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time of the termination. For example, TerminateThread can result in the following problems:
>
> - If the target thread owns a critical section, the critical section will not be released.
> - If the target thread is allocating memory from the heap, the heap lock will not be released.
> - If the target thread is executing certain kernel32 calls when it is terminated, the kernel32 state for the thread's process could be inconsistent.
> - If the target thread is manipulating the global state of a shared DLL, the state of the DLL could be destroyed, affecting other users of the DLL.

It's usually better to signal the thread in some manner (e.g. a boolean variable `bQuitRequested` that the thread occasionally checks) requesting the thread to quit, and then let the thread clean itself up and exit naturally with `ExitThread`. The calling process/thread can use `WaitForSingleObject`, passing it the thread handle. This blocks until the thread exits naturally, or until a timeout is reached.

Comment: Don't forget you'll need a mutex for `bQuitRequested`. Or use `InterlockedExchange(lQuitRequested, ...);`

Comment: For most thread-to-threadd communication, yes. But if it's a one-way notification that only gets flipped by the parent thread, I don't think one would be necessary. It shouldn't matter how the two threads race to that variable: if the child thread doesn't see the update this time around, we simply say it missed the bus, and it should catch it on its next loop.

Comment: You need memory barriers. Without a write barrier, the write to memory can be delayed infinitely; without a read barrier the read from memory can be delayed infinitely. Both of the synchronization mechanisms I suggested include full memory barriers.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are various possibilities:

1) Use the TerminateThread() API.  If the thread does not hold any locks of other resources that may/will be required by other threads/processes, then fine.  Note that this set of threads is very small and difficult to define exactly - don't use this method unless you are absolutely sure it is safe, (effectively, this means 'don't use it').

2) If the thread functionality is CPU-intensive, poll an 'Abort' boolean at some suitable level in your thread so that termination is sufficiently timely but without compromising its work too much, (ie. maybee not the innermost loop).

3) If the thread is usually blocked on some API, try to satisfy the API conditions 'early' so that the thread can be made running and so detect an abort boolean.  The exact mechanism to use depends on the particular blocking API.

4) Only terminate the thread on app shutdown, ie. let the OS do it when some other thread, (usually the main GUI thread) calls ExitProcess().  This requires some design constraints, eg. no comms between threads except through structures/mechanisms that outlive them all.

Rgds,
Martin